# Nested if statement in postgresql not working

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql. I am using 12.2 version. I am using simple nested if condition to check date functions. But it seems not working. There is no error, but the output is wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qa.check_date(
    d text)
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    STABLE SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

     date timestamp;
     v_check varchar(10);

BEGIN
     IF upper(d) <> 'NULL' THEN
         v_check:=LENGTH(trim(both TRANSLATE(d, '0123456789-./', ' ')));

        IF v_check = 0 OR coalesce(v_check::text, '') = 'NULL' THEN
             SELECT to_date(d, 'mm-dd-yyyy') INTO STRICT v_date;
             RETURN d;
        ELSE
             RETURN d;
        END IF;
     ELSE
        RETURN 'NULL';
     END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 'NaN/NaN/NaN';
END;
```

The output is always 'NaN/NaN/Nan'.
I tried with inputs like '05-01-2020','05-061-2020' but the output remains the same.

Comment: What is the variable `d`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `SELECT to_date(d, 'mm-dd-yyyy') INTO STRICT v_date;` can be simplified to `v_date := to_date(d, 'mm-dd-yyyy');`

Comment: You should show the complete function.

Comment: Why don't you remove the exception handler completely? Then you would actually see the error that causes this